How to use Bot app in different organization
I have created a Bot app using teams toolkit and run it locally. Using the teams toolkit, it has automatically created a app in developer portal of teams, created a app in app registrations in azure and a bot in botframework. The app in app registration in azure is supporting Multiple organizations. Now using this I have hosted the bot on server of which endpoint I have also mentioned. So the app is running in my tenant. Suppose I want my client which is other organization to install and use this bot without publishing into the marketplace. How and what to configure to use them. Or the user can have just upload the manifest file and use it even though it is registered in my tenant?
Thanks..

Yes they can just sideload the app in teams:
Apps -> Manage your Apps -> Upload an App -> Upload a custom App -> YourManifest.zip
An app may also be submitted to the organizations catalogue or submitted for approval in an orgs catalogue.
On installation this will create a new enterprise app in their Active Directory (entra) but no app registration, the app registration will remain solely in your own tenant.
The user doing this must have sufficient privileges, either individual or by having relaxed permissions at the tenant level. These permissions can be managed at https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/
You should also make sure your Entra app registration is multi-tenant:


The bot is not working properly. As they are getting error: '{"error":{"code":"BotNotInConversationRoster","message":"The bot is not part of the conversation roster."}}'.'.

I've added to my existing answer, try checking the authentication section of your app registration and making sure it's multi tenant. If your second tenant is using it in exactly the same way you are it's likely a permissions issue of some kind on the second tenant.
